# Python slicing with wrapping from negative to positive numbers

Tags: python, string, slice

Say I have a string "abcde", and want to get "deab". How can I get "deab" using string slicing?

I've tried using `string[-2:1]`, but this gives me an empty result `''`.

The project I am working on makes splitting this up into `[-2:]` and `[:2]` difficult, hence the question. Thanks!

Comment: You can't. Use two slices

Comment: why not splice from behind and concat from splice from front.

Comment: Slices don't wrap. No slice of `"abcde"` will produce `"deab"`.

Comment: What exactly makes it difficult?

Comment: You mean `[:2]` at the end, right?

Comment: @MadPhysicist you're right - just corrected it!

Comment: I don’t understand when you would be able to use `(s * 2)[3:7]` but not `s[-2:] + s[:2]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simulate wrapping by doubling the string:

```
(string * 2)[3:7]
```

This is not necessarily much less efficient than getting two slices the usual way: it only creates one temporary string instead of two, but obviously requires quite a bit more space.

Comment: very interesting

Comment: @ArpitSolanki. I'm glad you like it.

Comment: would have given like 100 upvotes but I can't. Made me laugh though

Comment: this is such a cool idea! I might use it if the space doesn't become an issue :)

Comment: @ilee. How many billions of characters do you have that you envision space being an issue?

Answer (score 3):

You may want this,

```
s[-2:] + s[:2]
```

Comment: Despite the fact that this is explicitly what OP is trying to avoid, it's the right answer. +1